# PowerShell: Tailing a log file, and sending results to the Windows system event log

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to tail a log file in Windows 2k8 using powershell, and then have it sent to the Windows event Viewer.

I know that powershell can 'tail' the log by running:

```
Get-Content -Path C:\logs\events.log -Wait
```

This will tail the logs in real time (similar to -f in linux tail).

Powershell can also write to Windows event system logs:

```
Write-EventLog System -source System -eventid 12345 -message "test"
```

I was wondering how (or if) I could pipe the tailed log results as the Write-EventLog message?

I'm thinking that since this is a Windows environment, it may need to be scripted to call a message variable taken from Get-Content? Does anyone know how, or if this can be done? My google searches haven't lead me to real time Windows event logging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably do something like this:

```
function Write-EventlogCustom($msg) {
    Write-EventLog System -source System -eventid 12345 -message $msg
}

Get-Content -Path C:\logs\events.log -Wait | % {Write-EventlogCustom $_}
```

You don't necessarily need to make a function, I just used it to make the code cleaner.

Comment: thanks. i wasn't 100% familiar with the powershell syntax, so much appreciated!